# How to embed version number in XAML TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0

How can I embed the program version in a `TextBlock` (or some other element instead ?) ?

```
<TextBlock>My Program version <tag Source={???}></tag></TextBlock>
```

What kind of `<tag>` should I use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Run :

```
 <TextBlock>
   My Program version
   <Run  Text="{Binding Version,Mode=OneWay}"/>
 </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 13):

you can bind to assembly version

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version

have

```
public string Version
{
  get{return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()}
}
```

in your viewmodel

and

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Version} />
```

Comment: This changes the whole text to the version number - I have to embed it as part of a larger text segment

Comment: This worked for me but it needs semicolon for us cut and piasters... it won't let me edit for just one character. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the MVVM design pattern and having a property exposed on your view model for the version number which you can then bind to in your view.

To get versions programmatically see http://all-things-pure.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/assembly-version-file-version-product.html

Comment: Could you please provide an example for an MVVM usage ? how do you apply it on my concrete problem ?

Comment: Perhaps start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx. Then use a framework http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx, e.g. Caliburn.Micro. You could also set the Text property in the code behind if you didn't want to learn MVVM.